# What is the equivalent of <% debug @variable %> for Haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, haml, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an annoying view problem that I'm trying to debug and no where on the Haml Documentation [Haml Docs](http://haml.info/docs.html) does it specify how to debug view code. This is very annoying and all I need is to debug a variable. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried `= debug @variable`?

Comment: I knew it had to be simple! I kept trying - debug @variable. Thanks...... I feel sheepish now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haml, to print a result on the page, you use `=` sign, so in your case it is:

```
= @variable.inspect
```

To write a conditional statement, for instance `if else`, you would use `-`:

```
-if condition
  # logic
-else
  #logic
```

Note, there is no `end`.

Comment: Thanks Andrey for distinguishing the difference. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found it best to put

```
`= debug(params)`
```

in your layouts/application.html.haml

Answer (score 0):

I just put debugger as below:

```
= f.input :hardware_configuration, collection: ['screen', 'screen_and_printer', 'printer_only']
= debugger
```

and it was there:

```
6:     = f.input :hardware_configuration, collection: ['screen', 'screen_and_printer', 'printer_only']  
7:     = debugger  
(byebug) n
```

Here you can check whatever variable is there directly(of course which you have declared and assigned in controller).

Note: I have `byebug` gem installed.